# Does adding a property to a mapping requires reindexing?

Tags: elasticsearch

The [docs on `_update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) says:

> The simplest usage of _update_by_query just performs an update on every document in the index without changing the source. **This is useful to pick up a new property or some other online mapping change.** Here is the API:
>
> ```
> POST twitter/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
> ```

(emphasis mine)

Plus the [introductory post to the Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/blog/reindex-is-coming) also exemplifies:

> ```
> # But now I want to search on tags using the standard analyzer so I can search for banana and find bananas
> ...
> # This doesn't take effect immediately
> ...
> # But we can _update_by_query to pick up the new mapping on all documents
> ```

So it appears that when you add a new property to a mapping, it won't be automatically indexed for past documents. I'm not 100% sure because the second example uses the word *immediately*, which gave me the impression that they *eventually* would. And in the first example, the concrete case presented is an index with Dynamic Mapping turned off.

So, to be absolutely sure, does adding a new property (or any kind of mapping update) **always** requires some kind of action (either update or reindex) so that previous documents have the new mapping applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very [few mapping changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) you can make to an existing mapping, the most common one being to add a sub-field to an existing field.

For instance, if you have a `text` field, you might want to add a `keyword` sub-field in order to enable sorting and aggregating on that field.

Mapping Before:

```
{
   "my_field": {
     "type": "text"
   },
   ...
}
```

Mapping After:

```
{
   "my_field": {
     "type": "text",
     "fields": {
       "keyword": {
         "type": "keyword"
       }
     }
   },
   ...
}
```

That mapping change can be made on a live index. The new documents will have both the `my_field` and `my_field.keyword` fields, while the older documents will only have `my_field`. In order to make sure all documents have both `my_field` and `my_field.keyword`, you can simply hit the `_update_by_query` API and all documents will be updated to satisfy the new mapping.

Note that the Update by query API works on the same index, while the Reindex API will not update the source index, but reindex data from a source index to a target one.